# I am uploading jpg and png formats only and trying to update already existed details but not working in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is the code I wrote for update details and image of a page. here I am uploading the file in jpg and png format only. But its showing:

> Sorry only png and png formats are allowed.

I stuck there. How can I overcome the issue?

```html
<?php
include 'db.php';



$target_dir = "banners/";
$target_file = $target_dir . microtime() . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== true) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}

if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
if($imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "JPEG"  && $imageFileType != "Jpeg" && $imageFileType != "PNG" && $imageFileType != "JPG") {

    echo "Sorry, only PNG and JPG files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";

} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
if($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]!=''){
$sql = "UPDATE `business_profile` SET `bs_name`='".$_POST['bsname']."',`bs_cat`='".$_POST['bscat']."',`mobile`='".$_POST['mobile']."',`email`='".$_POST['email']."',`location`='".$_POST['location']."',`addr`='".$_POST['addr']."',`image`='$target_file',`description`='".$_POST['desc']."' WHERE id='".$_POST['id']."'";
}else{
    
   $sql = "UPDATE `business_profile` SET `bs_name`='".$_POST['bsname']."',`bs_cat`='".$_POST['bscat']."',`mobile`='".$_POST['mobile']."',`email`='".$_POST['email']."',`location`='".$_POST['location']."',`addr`='".$_POST['addr']."',`description`='".$_POST['desc']."' WHERE id='".$_POST['id']."'";
 
    
}
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) { ?>
    
     <SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
    window.alert('Profile Added Succesfully')
    window.location.href='http://smartpuppies.in/admin/dashboard';
    </SCRIPT>
    
  <?php  }else{ ?>
         <SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
    window.alert('Error In adding , please try again. ')
    window.location.href='http://smartpuppies.in/admin/dashboard';
    </SCRIPT>
        
    <?php }



?>
```

This is the fo2rm I have. Here I have business details like business name, cateogory, their store image and new image of their store

```html
<form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" action="http://smartpuppies.in/some" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Business Name</label>
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <input class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" name="bsname"  value="<?php echo $row_req['bs_name']; ?>" type="text" required />
                      </div>
                    </div>  
                    
                    
                        <!--<div class="form-group">
                      <label for="" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Business Category</label>
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <input class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" name="bscat"  value="<?php echo $row_req['bs_cat']; ?>" type="text" required/>
                      </div>
                    </div> --->        
               
               <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row_req['id']; ?>" />
                       
                      
                              <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Phone No</label>
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <input class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" name="mobile"  value="<?php echo $row_req['mobile']; ?>" type="text"/>
                      </div>
                    </div> 
                    
                    
                          <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Email Id </label>
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <input class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" name="email"  value="<?php echo $row_req['email']; ?>" type="text"/>
                      </div>
                    </div> 
                        
                        
                                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Location</label>
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <input class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" name="location"  value="<?php echo $row_req['location']; ?>" type="text"/>
                      </div>
                    </div> 
                    
                    
                    
                                <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Adress</label>
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <input class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" name="addr"  value="<?php echo $row_req['addr']; ?>" type="text"/>
                      </div>
                    </div> 
                                <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Home Delivery </label>
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <input class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" name=""  value="<?php echo $row_req['del_option1']; ?>Rs,<?php echo $row_req['del_option2']; ?>Rs,<?php echo $row_req['del_option3']; ?>Rs" type="text" readonly/>
                      </div>
                    </div> 
                                <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Description  </label>
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <input class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" name="desc"  value="<?php echo $row_req['description']; ?>" type="text"/>
                      </div>
                    </div> 
                    
                     <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Store Image</label>
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <a href="http://www.smartpuppies.in/<?php echo $row_req['image'];?>" class="acustom" target="_blank"> Click  Me </a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    
                     <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Upload Image</label>
                      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <input  type="file" name="fileToUpload" class="margtopbottom"/>


                      </div>
                    </div>
                    
                                  
                                          
    <div class="text-center" >           

<input name="submit" value="Update" type="submit"/>
</div>
                  </form>
```

Comment: I would add some debug output such `echo "Target file is : " . $target_file;` and `echo "File type is : " . $imageFileType;`

Comment: _Suggestion:_ If you do: `$imageFileType = strtolower($imageFileType)`, you only need to check for the lower case version of the extension, making your if-statement way smaller.

Comment: **Warning:** You are also _wide open_ to SQL Injections and should use Prepared Statements instead of injecting unescaped user data straight into the query like that. That's a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: @cid-- Its not displaying the target file and file type

Comment: You need to do some debugging. It's impossible for us to do that for you. Put a `var_dump($_FILES, $target_file, $imageFileType); exit;` after the `pathinfo()`-line and update your question to include the output. You should probably also put all those lines inside the `if(isset($_POST["submit"]))` statement as well.

Comment: @Raghavendra would you please edit your post and add in your code where you placed your debug lines and show us the exact debug output?

Comment: @magnus eriksson, this is the output I got array(0) { } string(29) "banners/0.28499600 1528450752" string(19) "28499600 1528450752"

Comment: Then you don't have any uploaded files at all. Update the question and include the code for your form. You should also make sure you got `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in the top lines of your code while debugging. That should give you a bunch of _"undefined index"_ warnings.

Comment: @Cid, Magnus Eriksson I have updated with my form data. Check it once

Comment: When you did the debugging, did you add a file and posted the form to get that output? Are you using Ajax or something when posting?

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson Yes i uploaded a image and posted the form. I am not using ajax

Comment: In the top of your PHP-file, do `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])` and check if it says GET or POST. It can be that your posting to `http://smartpuppies.in/some` and that the web server does a redirect to `http://smartpuppies.in/some/` (with a trailing slash). Redirects are done using GET so in that case, you would lose all posted data. The solution would be to change the action to: `http://smartpuppies.in/some/` (with a trailing slash). If that's not the issue, then I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following

```
if($imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "JPEG"  && $imageFileType != "Jpeg" && $imageFileType != "PNG" && $imageFileType != "JPG") {

    echo "Sorry, only PNG and JPG files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
```

Into

```
$allowed =  array('png' ,'jpg','jpeg');
$imageFileType = strtolower($imageFileType);
if(!in_array($imageFileType,$allowed) ) {
    echo "Sorry, only PNG and JPG files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
```